# CQL3.2: DROP TABLE with certain prefix?

Tags: cassandra, cql, prefix

I have a Cassandra 2.1.8 database with a bunch of tables, all in the form of either "prefix1_tablename" or "prefix2_tablename".

I want to DROP every table that begins with prefix1_ and leave anything else alone.

I know I can grab table names using the query:

```
SELECT columnfamily_name FROM system.schema_columnfamilies
WHERE keyspace_name='mykeyspace'
```

And I thought about filtering the results somehow to get only prefix1_ tables, putting them into a table with DROP TABLE prepended to each one, then executing all the statements in my new table. It was similar thinking to strategies I've seen for people solving the same problem with MySQL or Oracle.

With CQL3.2 though, I don't have access to User-Defined Functions (at least according to the docs I've read...) and I don't know how to do something like execute statements off of a table query result, as well as even how to filter out prefix1_ tables with no LIKE operator in Cassandra.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a Bash shell script to solve my own issue. Once I realized that I could export the column families table to a CSV file, it made more sense to me to perform the filtering and text manipulation with grep and awk as opposed to finding a 'pure' cqlsh method.

The script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash

# No need for a USE command by making delimiter a period
cqlsh -e "COPY system.schema_columnfamilies (keyspace_name, columnfamily_name) 
TO 'alltables.csv' WITH DELIMITER = '.';"

cat alltables.csv | grep -e '^mykeyspace.prefix1_' \
    | awk '{print "DROP TABLE " $0 ";"}' >> remove_prefix1.cql

cqlsh -f 'remove_prefix1.cql'

rm alltables.csv remove_prefix1.cql
```

Comment: Nicely done!  That is A) awesome and B) exactly what I was going to suggest.